# How to use single ActionListener for JCheckBox and JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield, jcheckbox

I am writing an eJuice Calculator.  Its nowhere near finished as you will see below.  My question is: I have 4 JCheckBoxes, and 5 editable JTextFields; can I use one ActionListener to do have the program execute stuff.  Or do I need one listener for the CheckBoxes and one for the TextField?

This is a rough draft of code.

```
    package ejuicecalculatorv2;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    import javax.swing.*;

       public class EJuiceCalculatorV2 extends JFrame {
    //Form Controls
    private JCheckBox isPGbasedNic_CB       = new JCheckBox("PG Based NIC");
    private JCheckBox isPGbasedFlavor_CB    = new JCheckBox("PG Based Flavor");

    private JCheckBox isVGbasedNic_CB       = new JCheckBox("VG Based NIC");
    private JCheckBox isVGbasedFlavor_CB    = new JCheckBox("VG Based Flavor");

    private JTextField batchSize_TF         = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel batchSize_LB             = new JLabel("Batch Size:");

    private JTextField baseNicStrength_TF   = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel baseNicStrength_LB       = new JLabel("Base NIC Strength:");

    private JTextField targetNicStrength_TF = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel targetNicStrength_LB     = new JLabel("Target NIC Strength:");

    private JTextField totalNic_TF          = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel totalNic_LB              = new JLabel("Total NIC:");

    private JTextField flavorStrength_TF    = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel flavorStrength_LB        = new JLabel("Flavoring Strength:");

    private JTextField totalFlavor_TF       = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel totalFlavor_LB           = new JLabel("Total Flavoring:");

    private JTextField vgRatio_TF           = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel vgRatio_LB               = new JLabel("VG Ratio:");

    private JTextField pgRatio_TF           = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel pgRatio_LB               = new JLabel("PG Ratio:");

    private JTextField additionalVG_TF      = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel additionalVG_LB          = new JLabel("Additional VG:");

    private JTextField additionalPG_TF      = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel additionalPG_LB          = new JLabel("Additional PG:");

    private JTextField totalVG_TF           = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel totalVG_LB               = new JLabel("Total VG:");

    private JTextField totalPG_TF           = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel totalPG_LB               = new JLabel("Total PG:");

    private JTextField vgBasedIng_TF        = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel vgBasedIng_LB            = new JLabel("Total VG Ingredients:");

    private JTextField pgBasedIng_TF        = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel pgBasedIng_LB            = new JLabel("Total PG Ingredients:");


    //Variables
    private boolean _PGnicFlag;
    private boolean _VGnicFlag;

    private boolean _PGflavorFlag;
    private boolean _VGflavorFlag;

    private double baseNic;
    private double targetNic;
    private double totalNic;

    private double flavorStrength;
    private double totalFlavor;

    private double batchSize;

    private double totalPG;
    private double totalVG;

    private double additionalVG;
    private double additionalPG;

    private double pgBasedIng;
    private double vgBasedIng;

    private double pgRatio;
    private double vgRatio;


    public EJuiceCalculatorV2() {
        super("EJuice Calculator V2");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //Add CheckBoxes
        add(isPGbasedNic_CB);
        add(isPGbasedFlavor_CB);
        add(isVGbasedNic_CB);
        add(isVGbasedFlavor_CB);

        //Add TextFields and Labels
        add(batchSize_LB);
        add(batchSize_TF);

        add(vgRatio_LB);
        add(vgRatio_TF);

        add(pgRatio_LB);
        add(pgRatio_TF);

        add(baseNicStrength_LB);
        add(baseNicStrength_TF);

        add(targetNicStrength_LB);
        add(targetNicStrength_TF);

        add(flavorStrength_LB);
        add(flavorStrength_TF);

        //Add ActionListeners
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionHandler();
        isPGbasedNic_CB.addActionListener(actionListener);
        isPGbasedFlavor_CB.addActionListener(actionListener);
        isVGbasedNic_CB.addActionListener(actionListener);
        isVGbasedFlavor_CB.addActionListener(actionListener);
        batchSize_TF.addActionListener(actionListener);
        vgRatio_TF.addActionListener(actionListener);
        pgRatio_TF.addActionListener(actionListener);
        baseNicStrength_TF.addActionListener(actionListener);
        targetNicStrength_TF.addActionListener(actionListener);
        flavorStrength_TF.addActionListener(actionListener);     


        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

            //if event.getSource() == JCheckBox then execute the following code. 


            if(checkBox.isSelected()){
                if(checkBox == isPGbasedNic_CB){
                    _PGnicFlag = true;
                    _VGnicFlag = false;
                    checkBox = isVGbasedNic_CB;
                    checkBox.setSelected(false);                   
                }
                else if(checkBox == isVGbasedNic_CB){
                    _VGnicFlag = true;
                    _PGnicFlag = false;
                    checkBox = isPGbasedNic_CB;
                    checkBox.setSelected(false);
                }
                else if(checkBox == isVGbasedFlavor_CB){
                    _VGflavorFlag = true;
                    _PGflavorFlag = false;
                    checkBox = isPGbasedFlavor_CB;
                    checkBox.setSelected(false);
                }
                else if(checkBox == isPGbasedFlavor_CB){
                    _PGflavorFlag = true;
                    _VGflavorFlag = false;
                    checkBox = isVGbasedFlavor_CB;
                    checkBox.setSelected(false);
                }
            }
            else{
                if(checkBox == isPGbasedNic_CB){
                    _PGnicFlag = false;
                    _VGnicFlag = true;
                }
                else if(checkBox == isVGbasedNic_CB){
                    _VGnicFlag = false;
                    _PGnicFlag = true;
                }
                else if(checkBox == isVGbasedFlavor_CB){
                    _VGflavorFlag = false;
                    _PGflavorFlag = true;
                }
                else if(checkBox == isPGbasedFlavor_CB){
                    _PGflavorFlag = false;
                    _VGflavorFlag = true;
                }
            }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run (){
                new EJuiceCalculatorV2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing your code needs is a refactor, before anything else. You need to encapsulate these dozens of attributes in subcomponents. That's for your own sanity :p

Comment: A basic rule of thumb: use one listener for each specific action.

Comment: @Dici Its been a long while since I've programmed in Java.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's what I though. In the `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)` I had line that was `JCheckBox checkBox = (JCheckBox) event.getSource();`  This allowed for me set the flags and uncheck conflicting check boxes [in the following nested IF statements.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Is it possible to use `event.getSource()` to return the type of the object?

Comment: Please see edit to answer.

Comment: ...............................hello?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: I have 4 JCheckBoxes, and 5 editable JTextFields; can I use one ActionListener to do have the program execute stuff. Or do I need one listener for the CheckBoxes and one for the TextField?

You have a bunch of control components, but none appear ones that would initiate an action from the GUI. Rather all of them, the JCheckBoxes and the JTextFields are there to get input, and you appear to be missing one final component, such as a JButton. I would add this component to your GUi, and I would add a single ActionListener to it and it alone. And then when pressed, it would check the state of the check boxes and the text components and then based on their state, give the user the appropriate response.

Also some, if not most or all of the JTextFields, I'd change to either JComboBoxes or JSpinners, to limit the input that the user can enter to something that is allowable since you don't want the user entering "yes" into the "Batch Size" JTextField.

For example:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JSpinner.DefaultEditor;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JuiceTwo extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] FLAVORS = {"Flavor 1", "Flavor 2", "Flavor 3", "Flavor 4"};
    private static final Integer[] ALLOWABLE_BATCH_SIZES = {1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20};
    private static final String[] ALLOWABLE_VG_RATIOS = {"1/4", "1/3", "1/2", "1/1", "2/1", "3/1", "4/1", "8/1", "16/1"};
    private List<JCheckBox> flavorBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
    private JComboBox<Integer> batchSizeCombo;
    private JSpinner vgRatioSpinner;

    public JuiceTwo() {

        // JPanel to hold the flavor JCheckBoxes
        JPanel flavorPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1)); // hold them in vertical grid
        flavorPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Flavors"));
        for (String flavor : FLAVORS) {
            JCheckBox flavorBox = new JCheckBox(flavor);
            flavorBox.setActionCommand(flavor);
            flavorPanel.add(flavorBox);
            flavorBoxes.add(flavorBox);
        }

        batchSizeCombo = new JComboBox<>(ALLOWABLE_BATCH_SIZES);

        SpinnerListModel vgRatioModel = new SpinnerListModel(ALLOWABLE_VG_RATIOS);
        vgRatioSpinner = new JSpinner(vgRatioModel);
        JComponent editor = vgRatioSpinner.getEditor();
        if (editor instanceof DefaultEditor) {
            ((DefaultEditor)editor).getTextField().setColumns(4);
        }


        JButton getSelectionButton = new JButton("Get Selection");
        getSelectionButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        getSelectionButton.addActionListener(new SelectionActionListener());

        add(flavorPanel);
        add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        add(new JLabel("Batch Size:"));
        add(batchSizeCombo);
        add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        add(new JLabel("VG Ratio:"));
        add(vgRatioSpinner);
        add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        add(getSelectionButton);
    }

    private class SelectionActionListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (JCheckBox flavorBox : flavorBoxes) {
                System.out.printf("%s selected: %b%n", flavorBox.getActionCommand(), flavorBox.isSelected());
            }

            System.out.println("Batch Size: " + batchSizeCombo.getSelectedItem());            
            System.out.println("VG Ration:  " + vgRatioSpinner.getValue());

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JuiceTwo mainPanel = new JuiceTwo();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JuiceTwo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```